# Redis Sentinel not respecting announce-ip option

Tags: docker, redis, docker-compose, redis-sentinel

I am attempting to create a redis-sentinel cluster using docker-compose on my system and have it visible to the host machine (this is to try and replicate an application that is going to use redis-sentinel locally).

I have created the following `docker-compose.yaml` file to set up both the sentinel and redis itself

```
version: '2'

networks:
  app-tier:
    driver: bridge

services:
  redis-sentinel:
    image: s7anley/redis-sentinel-docker
    environment:
      - ANNOUNCE_IP=127.0.0.1
      - ANNOUNCE_PORT=26379
      - MASTER_NAME=mymaster
      - MASTER=redis
    networks:
      - app-tier
    ports:
      - '26379:26379'
  redis:
    image: bitnami/redis:latest
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    networks:
      - app-tier
    ports:
      - '6379:6379'
volumes:
  redis_data:
    driver: local
```

The sentinel manages to startup and finds the redis master correctly however it doesn't seem to respect the `announce-ip` option, in fact it appears to completely ignore it.

i.e. when I startup `redis-cli` on my host machine and ask for the address of master I get this

```
redis-cli -p 26379
127.0.0.1:26379> SENTINEL get-master-addr-by-name mymaster
1) "192.168.32.2"
2) "6379"
127.0.0.1:26379>
```

The reported ip should be `127.0.0.1` and not `192.168.32.2` (which is the internal IP that docker uses in the network)

This is the `sentinel.conf` file that is used in the docker image

```
port 26379
sentinel announce-ip 127.0.0.1
sentinel announce-port 26379
sentinel monitor mymaster redis 6379 2
sentinel down-after-milliseconds mymaster 30000
sentinel failover-timeout mymaster 180000
sentinel parallel-syncs mymaster
```

And this is what the config file looks like after redis-sentinel rewrites it after startup

```
port 26379
sentinel myid 4e7786e55f2b4ec31bdd36c1c3af6e2d3f2569e3
sentinel deny-scripts-reconfig yes
sentinel monitor mymaster 192.168.32.2 6379 2
sentinel config-epoch mymaster 0
sentinel leader-epoch mymaster 0
sentinel current-epoch 0
# Generated by CONFIG REWRITE
dir "/data"
sentinel announce-ip "127.0.0.1"
sentinel announce-port 26379
```

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

> sentinel announce-ip 127.0.0.1

That line applies to Sentinel, not to redis-server. It is the IP address that Sentinel will announce to other Sentinel's (they auto-discover each other). See [the relevant docs](https://redis.io/topics/sentinel#sentinel-docker-nat-and-possible-issues).

If you want redis to only listen on 127.0.0.1, I think putting this in the redis config should work:

> bind 127.0.0.1

By default redis bind's all network interfaces.